# Creating new view with match value from another table SQL

Tags: sql, join, replace, case, create-view

I have 2 tables like in the picture. In the first table I have column ID, in the second table I also have ID column and email column. In the end, I want a table 1 with specific email from table 2 which match with the ID column. Can you help me to create a view with this criteria?

Table 1 - Location:

```
| Location | Region |Senior_ID|Junior_ID|Manager_ID
| 1        | ACB    |xyz_123  |xyz_456  |
| 2        | YJT    |xyz_123  |xyz_456  |xyz_789
| 3        | HUP    |         |xyz_456  |xyz_789
```

Table2 - User:

```
| Name     | ID         |Email
| Mark     | xyz_123    |Mark@gmail.com
| Toby     | xyz_456    |Toby@gmail.com
| Elena    | xyz_789    |Elena@gmail.com
```

Final Table:

```
| Location | Region |Senior_mail    |Junior_mail     |Manager_mail
| 1        | ACB    |Mark@gmail.com |Toby@gmail.com  |
| 2        | YJT    |Mark@gmail.com |Toby@gmail.com  |Elena@gmail.com
| 3        | HUP    |               |Toby@gmail.com  |Elena@gmail.com
```

I tried with select and case when a.ID = b.ID but it will create new column. I only want to replace the ID in the first column with email.

Comment: A [mcve] would make this much clearer.

Comment: Simply LEFT JOIN User table three times, i.e. once for each e-mail.

Answer (score 0):

`users` should act as separate tables for *seniors*, *juniors* and *managers*.

```
   select l.location,
     l.region,
     s.email senior_mail,
     j.email junior_mail,
     m.email manager_mail
   from location l left join users s on s.id = l.senior_id
                   left join users j on j.id = l.junior_id
                   left join users m on m.id = l.manager_id
   order by l.location;

  LOCATION REG SENIOR_MAIL     JUNIOR_MAIL     MANAGER_MAIL
---------- --- --------------- --------------- ---------------
         1 ACB mark@gmail.com  toby@gmail.com
         2 YJT mark@gmail.com  toby@gmail.com  elena@gmail.com
         3 HUP                 toby@gmail.com  elena@gmail.com
```